# How to color part of the java code in android studio ?

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, androidstudio-settings

there is some way i can color in some color part of my code (not the output, the actually code ) in android studio ?

something like this :

```
 case R.id.buttonbackup:
            Toast.makeText(this, "first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                Toast.makeText(this, "before try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                BackUpContacts();
                DeleteAllContacts();

                Toast.makeText(this, "after try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "EX", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this,e.getStackTrace().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {//this the part i want to color 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
```

i want to color all the part of the catch . there is some way to do that ?